# Failing a stage but keeping build result as Successful in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following code as a Jenkins scripted pipeline:

```
node {  
    stage('Stage 1') { 
        echo "1"
    }
    stage('Stage 2') { 
        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
            sh "exit 1"
        }
    }
          
    stage('Stage 3') { 
        echo "3"
    }
  }
}
```

This successfully produces what I want in Jenkins, that is, I want the build to be successful but `stage 2` to fail.

[image]

What I don't understand is what exactly `sh "exit 1"` is doing here. If I do anything else here, `Stage 2` is not marked as "Failed". What is `sh "exit 1"` doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exit 1` is the exit code in shell script which means **to catch for all general errors**

Here refer to this guide [Exit Codes With Special Meanings](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html)

So, in the pipeline stage, you have put the `sh "exit 1"` inside the [catchError](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result-to-failure) block which means it will exit the shell script with **exit code 1** (i.e. any general error) and the `catchError` block will catch that error causing the particular stage to fail but build result to pass.